# LaTeX figure rendering incorrectly

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

The following code:

```
\clearpage
\section{Section 1.2}

This is a paragraph.

The details page should look like the following:

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5.5in]{resources/fig1.5.png}
    \caption{Figure 1.5}
\end{figure}
```

Is producing the following output:

[image: Output]

As you can see, the figure is displaying above the text. My intention is for the figure to come below the text. How can I force this behavior? I put the `\clearpage` command at the top because otherwise the Section 1.2 heading was appearing at the bottom of the previous page with the text and figure following on the next page (which I did not want). In case it is relevant, I am using `\documentclass{book}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It looks like this question has been asked here before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: Also consider reading section **3 The User Interface - [H] Placement Specifier** of the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf#page=3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the placement specifiers:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5.5in]{resources/fig1.5.png}
    \caption{Figure 1.5}
\end{figure}
```